# Vuetify 3 Gutters

Tags: vue.js, grid, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to create a `v-row` without gutters (red background) in **Vuetify 3** and it's driving me insane. I'd like it to contain the entire width of the screen so there are no spaces between. Can anyone help out?

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-main>
      <div class="maple">
        <row no-gutters>
          <v-col>
            <h1>Have a Showmax Festive</h1>
            <div v-for="image in images" :key="image">
              <v-img :src="image"></v-img>
            </div>
          </v-col>
        </row>
      </div>
    </v-main>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

I've tried using the `no-gutters` props according to the documentation on Vuetify and `container-fluid` is still nogo.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!!

I was supposed to use div class="row"

Instead of

Maybe its something wrong with my personal Vuetify setup though but this seems to work perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, instead of `<v-row no-gutters>` you have `<row no-gutters>`.

Just changes both instances of `row`, to `v-row` and you should be good to go :)

This typo was unfortunate, because `<row>` is still valid, if you had missed `v` and had `<-row>` your IDE/Browser should've let you know lol.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. unfortunately I already tried that and it doesn't seem to work. 

This is the Link to my project
http://192.168.0.154:8080/

You see there's some spacing surrounding the container of the component.

Comment: That link unfortunately only works from inside your house/on your network